# How to use merge

Tags: jpa, merge, ejb, managed

In my Web tier I show a list of Tasks and for each task it shows how many TaskErrors it has. The tasks are fetched in a controller class this way:

```
public List<Task> getTasks () {
    return taskEJB.findAll();
}
```

Task has a @OneToMany mapping with TaskErrors: a task can have multiple task errors.

When I delete a single TaskError, a controller in the Web tier calls TaskErrorFacade:remove(taskError). TaskErrorFacade is a stateless session bean. The code:

```
public void remove (TaskError taskError) {
    entityManager.remove(entityManager.merge(taskError));

    Task task = taskError.getTask();
    task.deleteTaskError(taskError);
    task = entityManager.merge(task);
}
```

Task:deleteTaskErrors(TaskError taskError) simply deletes the task from the List:

```
public void deleteTaskError (TaskError p_error) {
    taskErrorCollection.remove(p_error); // gives true
}
```

This works. The Web tier shows a tabel with all the task and the number of Task Errors it has. The number drops by 1 after deleting a TaskError.

But... the following two implementations of  TaskErrorFacade:remove(taskError) don't work: the tabel in the Web tier doesn't subtract 1 of the total Task Error count (however, they are deleted in the database):

```
public void remove (TaskError taskError) {
    entityManager.remove(entityManager.merge(taskError));

    Task task = taskError.getTask();
    task = entityManager.merge(task); // the merge is done before the deletion
    task.deleteTaskError(taskError);

}
```

And:

```
public void remove (TaskError taskError) {
    entityManager.remove(entityManager.merge(taskError));

    taskError.getTask().deleteTaskError(taskError); // no merge
}
```

Why are the two implementations above not working?

[image]

**Edit:** also important are the mappings of the relations. Task is mapped in TaskError this way:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "task_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Task task;
```

Comment: Do you have default transaction attribute set for your SLSB? How do you show data in the web tier? In your controller code what is `taskEJB` and how is its `findAll()` method defined?

Comment: Yes, CMT (standard) transactions in my SLSB. The webtier puts the data in a primefaces datatable. In my controller code taskEJB refers to TaskFacade: a SLSB with EntityManager to do some CRUD.